# Changing Component Property from Directive in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 1 app that works with a simple `contentEditable` directive, which can be used like this in templates:

```
<span contenteditable="true"  ng-model="model.property" placeholder="Something">
```

Editing the element would fire `$setViewValue(element.html()` and it worked as expected.

I would like to make something in Angular2 with a similarly succinct template syntax. Ideally, I would like the template to look like this:

```
<span contentEditable="true" [(myProperty)]="name"></span>
```

where 'name' is a property on the component and have the directive update the component when changed. I feel like I'm close with this ([Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/LNg21LqAwHpbjFzI7cMq)):

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Input, Output Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'

@Directive({
    selector: '[contentEditable]',
    host: {
        '(blur)': 'update($event)'
    }
})

export class contentEditableDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() myProperty;
    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer){}

    update(event){
      this.myProperty = this.el.nativeElement.innerText;
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        this.el.nativeElement.innerText =  this.myProperty; 
    }
}
```

This idea works if I pass an object like `{name: "someName"}` but if just pass a property it seems like it's passing the value, but not the reference and so the binding doesn't flow back to the component. Is there a way to do this that will still allow a template syntax that isn't verbose but still allows easy reuse of the directive.

Comment: I'll add that I can do this if I  add 2 inputs to the directive and pass both the object and property name as separate inputs. My template would then look like this: `<myElement contentEditable="true" [myobject]="anobject" property="somevalue">` Then I can manipulate `myobject[property]` from the directive. Would prefer a cleaner way though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The directive doesn't know about its parent `name` property. You can though emit an event from the directive and catch it in the parent. Check this example

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[contentEditable]',
    host: {
        '(input)': 'update($event)' // I changed it to input to see the changes immediatly
    }
})
export class contentEditableDirective implements OnInit {

// Output that will emit outside the directive
@Output() updateProperty: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

// When 'update' is called we emit the value
update(event){
  this.updateProperty.emit(this.el.nativeElement.innerText);
}
```

Now that our directive is emitting correctly, we have to catch the value in the component. *For brevity only the template*

```js
<div contentEditable="true" [myProperty]="name" (updateProperty)="name = $event"></div>
```

`updateProperty` is the `@Output` from the directive. When it gets triggered we catch it and the value we emied will be assigned to `$event`. After that we assign `$event` to our property `name` and you got your app working.

Here's your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/O1gdN64A9O4V6zvcAv1z?p=preview) working. I hope it helps.

## Update

Thank to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34736161/how-do-i-create-a-dropdown-component-in-angular-2) I saw that it is possible what you asked for.

You can match the Output to what is called when the syntax `[()]` is desugared. If you have a syntax like `[(myProperty)]="expr"` it is desugared to `[myProperty]="expr" (myPropertyChange)="expr = $event"`

So changing the original answer to as follows

```js
@Output() myPropertyChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
update(event){
  this.myPropertyChange.emit(this.el.nativeElement.innerText);
}
```

It will give you this template, which is what you asked from the beginning.

```
<div contentEditable="true" [(myProperty)]="name"></div>
```

Here's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z2T6ZGvkvtqfdKYQObMy?p=preview) updated to the real correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for this Eric - this helped. This seems to be the way Angular2 wants us to wire things up. It's going to a take a little while for me to get used to. I can't help thinking it might be better just to have my component handle this directly, since it's so simple.

Comment: @MarkM I updated my answer to reflect what you really asked for. I'm really sorry if I mislead you.

Comment: Yes! That is a much nicer solution. Thanks for the update - I don't think I would have ever figured that out.

Comment: @EricMartinez what triggers the update function in your final answer?

Answer (score 6):

I found this very smooth solution that worked for my case (adding a readonly role to existing UI) using the @Host decorator for injecting the component you want to set property of in the Directive. In my case I have an abstract class with readonly property that is then extended by all custom components.

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'authCheck'
})
export class ComponentReadonlyDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthorizationService,
              @Host() private baseComponent: BaseComponent) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.authorizationService.canEdit()) {
      this.baseComponent.readonly = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Where in the selector part I put directly the selectors of my custom components that implement the BaseComponent (e.g. my-comp). This is because I want the directive to be automatically applied to all instances of my-comp. I have an additional param that can turn the directive off.

If this is a single component to use the directive - put it on the place of BaseComponent.

If multiple components will use the same directive - you'll need to specify what will be injected on the @Host parameter by specifying a provider in the extending class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  ...
  providers: [{
      provide: BaseComponent, useExisting: forwardRef(() => MyComp)
  }]
})
export class MyComp extends BaseComponent { ... }
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13776

Answer (score 3):

If you simply want to change the **value** using pure **JavaScript** and *do not* want to go towards the **[(model])** route, then this is for you.

```
const input = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector('#myElement');
input.value = 'My Programmatic Value';
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Issue - https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/696

Solution - https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/696#issuecomment-354887412

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers!