# Programatically update input value from directive in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this template in a component:

```
...
<div class="myCustomDirective">
    <input name="value" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" />
</div>
...
```

I want to update the value from `myCustomDirective`. Updating the input element directly like this:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('input').value = 'bla';
```

... doesn't update the model in the component.

Using Angular 4.2.6.

Comment: If you are using "banana-in-a-box" notation (the [()] thing), just change the value of the the variable "value" that you linked.

Comment: Again, this template is a part of a **component**. I'm trying to update the value from a completely independent **directive**.

Comment: What's your use case? Why and when do you want to modify the `input` value?

Comment: I have a custom spinner text box with + and - buttons. + increases the value, - decreases it.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more context and code, as it's not very clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's very easy. I have a generic directive that needs to be able to update an input element. That I can do. How to propagate this down to `ngModel` is what troubles me.

Comment: Thanks @Pablo. The "possible duplicate" link worked. Posting my solution below.

Comment: where is this directive placed? can it be placed on the `input` element?

Comment: @Maximus: it can be placed anywhere - on the same level or above.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Pablo and his link [Changing Component Property from Directive in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846394/changing-component-property-from-directive-in-angular2), I found my solution.

In directive:

```
import {
    EventEmitter,
    Output
} from '@angular/core'

@Output() updateValue: EventEmitter < any > = new EventEmitter();

inAnyFunction() {
    this.updateValue.emit('bla');
}
```

In component:

```
...
<div (updateValue)="value = $event">
...
```

I'm more and more disappointed by Angular every day. If I'm using `[(ngModel)]` I would expect that updating the input element programatically (because why is it different when I update the input element manually and programatically?) would propagate the change. Useless framework that creates more problems than solutions.

Comment: I've avoided the ngModel approach from the beginning, using reactive forms means more work at the beginning but in the end saves you a lot of headaches

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Dispatch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) ('Input' one) in your directive after programmatic change. (ngModel) works as event listener, so that is the actual difference between manually and programmatically.

```
       this.element.nativeElement.value = 'new value';
       this.element.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input'));
```

Answer (score 1):

use your directive as input tag like

```
<input myCustomDirective name="value" type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

import and initialize ElementRef

```
 constructor(  public _el: 
     ElementRef) {
      }
```

and then you can easily change the value by

```
 this._el.nativeElement.value="your value"
```

it will also update model
if you want to change model at every change then

```
  import { Directive,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {NgModel}from '@angular/forms';

  @Directive({
      selector: '[number][ngModel]',
        host: {'(ngModelChange)': 'doSomething($event)'}  
  })
  export class NumberDirective{
    constructor(  public _el: 
     ElementRef) {
      }
     doSomething(event){
       console.log(event);
       event=event.slice(4,event.length);
        this._el.nativeElement.value="check"+event;
     }  
  }
```

and in html

```
 <input number [(ngModel)]="inputVal" (ngModelChange)="inputVal=$event" />
```