# How to use Bootstrap drop down in Angular2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, bootstrapping

In my current project I want to add the dropdowns, for that I took the code from this [link](http://bootswatch.com/default/#navbar). After added the below code, the dropdown appears as in the example but when I click it nothing happens.

```
   <li class="dropdown">
                <a [routerLink]="['/frontendai']" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Application Insights <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/frontendai']">FrontEnd AI</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/apiai']">API AI</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/apiai']">SQL Exception</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

I used Bootstrap version 3.3.7, and added the below lines in my **index.cshtml**

```
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

How can I use Bootstrap dropdown in Angular 2 project?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736563/2448440) to get an idea how you can separate the code into a separate angular component.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ngx-bootstrap is available for Angular Project.(above version 2).

Here is link : http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

You can use it on your project.

Instructions

**do `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`**

**Import Dropdown Module**

```
// RECOMMENDED (doesn't work with system.js)
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
// or
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}

<div class="btn-group" dropdown>
  <button dropdownToggle type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul *dropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li role="menuitem"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the ngx-bootstrap dependency in package.json but still I faced same issue.

Comment: Did you followed instruction? or can you share any plunker? then it would be great.

Comment: Actually bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap is little different. I will edit answer.

Answer (score 5):

To use bootstrap dropdown in angular you need add two classes - 
one **show** class at parent dropdown element i.e. dropdown and other **show** class at its child dropdown-menu.

To do that you can either create a dropdown compenent and pass list of values as an array to it with their click handlers or create a custom directive.

Custom Dropdown directive approach:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDropdown]'
})
export class DropdownDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  //Binding click to Add show class 
  @HostListener('click') onclick() {

    var parent = this.el.nativeElement;//parent element
    parent.classList.toggle('show');
    var child = [].filter.call(this.el.nativeElement.children, function(ele) {
      return ele.classList.contains('dropdown-menu');
    }); //Identify the child element on dropdown clicked- dropdwon menu

    if(child.length) {
      child[0].classList.toggle('show');
    }
  }

}
```

Now in the template attach this at bootstrap dropdown:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown" appDropdown>
   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"  id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
     Username
   </a>
   <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" >Profile 2</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" >Logout 2</a>
   </div>
 </li>
```

**NOTE** - This solution is for Bootstrap 4 Dropdown only, for Boostrap 3 you need to identify the classes that need to be attached. It must be **open** class on parent level only.

Comment: Thank you this is much simpler than bringing in an extra dependency (nothing against ngx-bootstrap but this is pretty easy to implement yourself once I knew what class to add to what element).  Just a note you can also just use ngClass to apply the classes to the appropriate element also I think the .toggle function on classList will add/remove as needed.

Comment: IMO opinion, this should be the answer, as the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question.